# Do US Taxi cabs come inside the cemetery like this?

Tags: usa, taxis

I watching US Marshals (1998) movie, Man with green hat hired a taxi and it 
dropped him at chapel which is inside the cemetery.

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't they? Sufficiently large cemeteries have roads so you can drive around inside of them. Why would the taxi driver throw their passenger out at the gate instead of taking them where they want to go?

Comment: I too find it weird to see a vehicle inside a cemetery. Probably a cultural difference... My hometown has an 84-acre cemetery, one of the largest in France, and if you want to visit, you'll have to walk.

Comment: @ZachLipton it is unusual (although not unheard off) for vehicles to enter cemeteries in most of Europe. Hence the question (I imagine).

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose Good point. What a cemetery means varies a lot depending on cultural expectations. Most US cemeteries I've seen, excepting old or small ones, have at least some roads, certainly roads to any chapel inside, and it's not uncommon to hire towncars to carry family members if there is going to be a funeral procession. I can see how that would seem quite strange if you're not used to seeing that at home.

Comment: North-Americans have everything as drive-throughs.  That includes cemeteries.  I lived next to a drive-through cemetery when in Toronto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it's not uncommon in a large city like New York City, USA, where many people do not own a car and would not have an easy way to get to the cemetary otherwise.

It's also pretty common to go to historic cemeteries like the *Arlington National Cemetery* in Arlington, Virginia, USA.  There was an article in the newspaper the *Washington Post*, a story of a Taxi Cab driver who was repeatedly fined for waiting to pick up passengers near the cemetery without a public transportation permit. The story notes that a county permit was needed to pick up passengers anywhere in the county, even within Arlington National Cemetery, which is technically federal property.  The Taxi driver did not have that permit, which is the reason why he got fined, not that he could not drive into the cemetery.